# Unable to install 12.04 on a Lenovo U410 Ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, installation, lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo U410 Ultrabook and tried installing 12.04. Once I enter the installation process, I am not able to see available partitions.

Is it because of the 32GB SSD that is available in the HDD? If so, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you installing?

Answer (score 2):

The U410 comes with both disks in RAID0 configuration.

If you do a Ubuntu only install, you can disable this in the BIOS ( <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS, under configuration, RAID option AHCI which is standard S-ATA), the disks now show up as you would expect.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and got a blue screen on boot and then it went right to windows recovery when I tried to boot to windows.  Does the ubuntu install fix something so windows can boot properly? (iRST was enabled as well)

Answer (score 2):

It is said [**here**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1825132):

> Once you use a SSD with Intel's Smart Response Technology (SRT) the SSD will be unavailable to other operating systems. This is because you will have to use Intel's Rapid Storage Technology (RST) driver that is only available for Windows to access the drive.