# Recent notebooks incompatible with ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, hardware

I'm thinking about purchasing a laptop. Since without Linux it would be for me a worthless object, let me ask the following:

- Are there recent note- or ultrabooks that cannot support Ubuntu 12.10 installation?
- Are there notebooks that work considerably below the features they promise when one uses Ubuntu?

(I posted this question because I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184545/unable-to-install-12-04-on-a-lenovo-u410-ultrabook) and I'm afraid of buying something that won't work).

Comment: System76 or the certified hardware page for tips on the "right" hardware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, due to the fact that hardware developers often do not bother themselves with supporting anything but Windows, and often do not release specifications for the hardware, there may be sometimes a lag between a product appearing on the market and support for it added to Linux. The situation improved quite a bit over the last years though, with major hardware developers supporting Linux.

If you want to avoid problems with device support in Ubuntu, you're advised to buy a laptop with [Ubuntu pre-installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed) from one of the manufacturers which sell such machines, or refer to [Ubuntu Desktop certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) document.

If you have a particular laptop on your mind and it's not in the list of certified hardware - it does not mean it won't work with Ubuntu though, in many cases everything works just fine, but you need to search google to see if there any problems with that particular model.